# Cisco AnyConnect: Certificate Failure while ssh'd in

Tags: vpn, certificate

`/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin vpn connect HOST` works from the command line, but not after `ssh localhost`. How can I make these certificates available to myself after ssh'ing in?

Comment: I think there's a useful question here, but I can't make it out. From where to where is the ssh connection? What does "works from the command line" mean in practice - what sort of VPN tunnel are you activating? Where precisely does the certificate failure manifest itself?

Comment: from anywhere to the box.  in this case, from the box to itself (`ssh localhost`).  this is Cisco annyconnect.  whatever it's activating with the above command.  it just works when I type it onto the command line, but not after I `ssh localhost`.